# Why does typealiasing a tuple of a generic protocol in Swift allow me to treat it as a non-generic protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

I'm having trouble understanding why typealiasing a tuple of a generic protocol suddenly allows me to treat it as a non-generic protocol. Because of the way Swift generics work, we expect the errors we get in Examples 1, 3, 4 and 5. But why does Example 2 work? And how is it semantically different from Example 3?

## Example 1:

As expected, this won't compile:

```
let foo: Hashable = "a" // error: protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Because `Hashable` inherits the `Self` requirement from `Equatable`.

## Example 2:

But if I define a tuple of `Hashable`, it works!

```
typealias CompositeHashable = (Hashable, Hashable)
let foo: CompositeHashable = (1, "a") // This works!
```

Now I no longer need to use `Hashable` as a generic constraint.

## Example 2b:

I can even use `CompositeHashable` in a collection:

```
let bar: [CompositeHashable] = [(1, "a"), ("b", "a")] // This works!
```

## Example 3:

Interestingly, if I don't typealias the tuple, it doens't work.

```
let foo: (Hashable, Hashable) = (1, "a") // error: protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

That should have been equivalent to Example 2, right?

## Example 4:

Additionally, a 1-tuple doesn't work either, with or without typealias:

```
typealias HashableTuple = (Hashable)
let foo: HashableTuple = ("a") // error: protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

## Example 5:

One more piece to this.. if I take the previous typealias `CompositeHashable` from Example 2, and simply move it into a struct, it now gives the same error we expected in the other cases.

```
struct CompositeKey {
    typealias CompositeHashable = (Hashable, Hashable) // error: protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
}
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Definitely seems like a bug..

Answer (score 0):

```
typealias CompositeHashable = (Hashable, Hashable)
CompositeHashable.self

// it is OK !!!!!

let foo: CompositeHashable = (1, "a") // This works!
foo.0.dynamicType   // Int.Type
foo.1.dynamicType   // String.Type
foo.dynamicType     // (Hashable, Hashable).Type

Any.self            // protocol<>.Protocol

let bar: [CompositeHashable] = [(1, "a"), ("b", "a")]
bar.dynamicType // Array<(Hashable, Hashable)>.Type    Hashable.self // error: protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

....
this one is interesting

```
let foo: HashableTuple = ("a")
```

> Void is a typealias for the empty tuple type, (). **If there is only one
>   element inside the parentheses, the type is simply the type of that
>   element.** For example, the type of (Int) is Int, not (Int). As a
>   result, you can name a tuple element only when the tuple type has two
>   or more elements.

this is equivalent of your typealias

```
let (a,b) = ("a",1)
typealias Htuple = (A:Hashable,B:Hashable)
let t:Htuple = (a,b)
```

Comment: That quote explains why Example 4 doesn't work, there is no distinction between (Hashable) and Hashable. But I don't understand what you are trying to say in your code snippet.

Comment: foo is type of touple. you first create the tuple (Int, String) and next you assign it to variable with type tuple. Int conforms to Hashable and String conforms to Hashable, so (Int, String) has the same type as foo.

Comment: the same for Array bar (2b). bar has type Array<(Hashable, Hashable)>.Type array of tuples

Comment: think about your CompositeHashabe. the type is tuple where first property must conform to Hashable, second property must conform to Hashable. so tuple.  (Int, String) is not the same as (Hashable, Hashable)! the tuple (Int, String) just fulfill requirements of CompositeHashable